# Extracting instance variable from object stored in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make Go using PyGame. I have a class:

```
class Piece():

    def __init__(self,pos,colour):
        
        global circle
        super().__init__()
        self.show_colour = colour
        circle = pg.draw.circle(screen,color,(pos[0],pos[1]),20)

    def return_colour(self):
        return self.show_colour
```

I store the objects in a NumPy array and I am trying to extract them from the array to figure out the colour of the object in that position:

```
piece_colour = piece_board[y][x].return_colour()
```

When this code runs I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'return_color'
```

I have never used classes before it may be that I am doing something wrong.

I have to tried to get the object first and then extract that variable but that gave the same error.

```
piece_type = piece_board[y][x]
piece_color = piece_type.return_color()
```

I am not too familiar with classes so I wasn't sure how to change this to get a different result.

I also tried changing the default type of the item in the array but that has not changed the result.

---

Fixed the issue:
I printed piece_board[y][x] and it printed:`[<__main__.Piece object at 0x000001603C98AE90>]`.
I had done this before but was dumb and hadn't realized that it was a list. So I now have:`piece_colour = Piece.return_color(piece_board[y][x][0])` which solves my issue.

Comment: if you are using `global` inside of a class, that is almost always code smell

Comment: I'm new to classes, I put it there when I first created it in case it was needed but I removed it and hasn't changed anything

Comment: Try `print(piece_board[y][x])` and see what is printed.

Comment: @ken Tried it before and did realize that I printed the list:
[<__main__.Piece object at 0x000001603C98AE90>] so I extracted it and I now works, thanks you! I was dumb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed the issue: I printed `piece_board[y][x]` and it printed:`[<__main__.Piece object at 0x000001603C98AE90>]`. I had done this before but was dumb and hadn't realized that it was a list. So I now have: `piece_colour = Piece.return_color(piece_board[y][x][0])` which solves my issue.

Answer (score -4):

return_color is not a function you call on a variable. you call the variable as a parameter to the function.

`piece_colour = Piece.return_colour(piece_board[y][x])`

Comment: I just tried it but I get a different error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'show_color'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).